# Mann-Whitney-Wilcxon Test Adjustments

Tags: nonparametric, sas, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am trying to replicate a Mann-Whitney test that was done. All I have are the data and the standardized statistic.

```
data mann_whitney_counts;
input dose gender $ count @@;
datalines;
8  M  3   8  F  2
9  M  0   9  F  3
10 M  8   10 F  9
11 M  19  11 F  12
12 M  3   12 F  0
;
run;
```

When I run proc npar1way, I get a standardized statistic of Z = -1.81. However, the report I am trying to replicate has Z = -2.55. I'm trying to figure out what adjustments may have been made in that calculation. I've already considered ties adjustment and continuity correction.

Any thoughts/comments are greately appreciated! Thank you!

```
proc npar1way data = mann_whitney_counts correct = no wilcoxon;
    class gender;
    var dose;
    freq count;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: What other information does the report have?  It should state the value of the statistic, at least.

Comment: With that high of a z-score (2.55), the only way anything comes close is to run a chi-squared test of the count frequencies across the two genders, then take the square root of chi-squared.  However, the d.f. is 4, and you can't sqrt chi-squared to get a standard normal Z-score if the d.f.>1.  Other than that, it might be due to use of Wilcoxon rank sum test instead of Mann-Whitney.  You used Wilcoxon rank sum in SAS, and not MW.   So see if you can use MW in SAS.  But i doubt there will be such a large difference in Z between Wilcoxon rank sum and MW.  Could be due to handling ties.

Comment: What's that first column, that has been labelled "dose"? Can you clarify the meaning of the variables and what the hypothesis is?